# Error getting token on interceptor - Type 'Promise<void | Observable<HttpEvent<any>>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am creating an interceptor to send the token along with the requests for the Api.

I use `@ionic/storage` to store my user information. However, when I try to get the token in the constructor to save to a variable (eg private token: string), my interceptor can not get that value even though the token exists. *I believe this happens because the intercept is executed before the this.storage.get function ends.*

How can I fix this?

I've tried putting the `this.storage.get` function inside the intercept, but the return error:

> Type 'Promise < void | Observable < HttpEvent < any >>>' is not
>   assignable to type 'Observable< HttpEvent< any>>'. Property
>   '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Promise< void | Observable<
>   HttpEvent>>'.

Look at the code:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {  
    return this.storage.get('token')
        .then((token) => {
            if (token) {
                const newRequest = req.clone({ setHeaders: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` } });

                return next.handle(newRequest);
            } else {
                return next.handle(req);
            }
        })
        .catch(() => {
            //TODO: Trata erro
        })
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: what does `this.storage.get` return? (An Http Promise?)

Comment: According to the documentation (https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/), return only Promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the storage promise to an `Observable` before returning it:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    var promise = this.storage.get('token')
        .then((token) => {
            if (token) {
                const newRequest = req.clone({ setHeaders: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` } });

                return next.handle(newRequest);
            } else {
                return next.handle(req);
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            //TODO: Trata erro
            throw error;
        })
    return Observable.fromPromise(promise);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `Promise` into an `Observable` with the [`Observable.fromPromise`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-fromPromise) method.